# How to create a dictionary of dictionaries using dict comprehension?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I am trying to create a dictionary of dictionaries using a dict comprehension over a list of lists.

The list of lists contains student names, assignment names and grades. For example, the data could look like this:

```
grades_lists = [
    ['Student', 'Test', 'Assignment', 'Exam'],
    ['Bella', '80', '90', '100'],
    ['Sam', '65', '75', '85'],
    ['Emily', '60', '75', '90'],
]
```

I want to create a dictionary that maps the student names to dictionaries containing the assignment name and grade. For example:

```
grades_dicts['Bella']['Test'] == 80
```

The dictionary I would like is this:

```
{
    'Bella': {'Test': 80, 'Assignment': 90, 'Exam': 100},
    'Sam': {'Test': 65, 'Assignment': 75, 'Exam': 85},
    'Emily': {'Test': 60, 'Assignment': 75, 'Exam': 90}
}
```

so each row in `grades_list` becomes a dictionary; the first column is the name of the student, the other columns are values in a dictionary whose keys are taken from the first row from `grades_list`.

I have been trying to use dict comprehension to generate the corresponding keys and values in the dictionaries. Something like this:

```
grade_dicts = {x[0]:{y:z} for y in grades_lists[0][1:] for x in grades_lists[1:] for z in x[1:]}
```

But this does not generate all of the grades correctly:

```
{
    'Bella': {'Exam': '100'},
    'Emily': {'Exam': '90'},
    'Sam': {'Exam': '85'}
}
```

Comment: How do you expect your dictionary to look like?

Comment: ... Create **dictionary** with **list** comprehension? What you're using is **dictionary** comprehension.

Comment: You can't create a dictionary with a list comprehension, no. You are using a *dictionary* comprehension instead.

Comment: *But this does not generate all of the grades correctly*. So what happens instead, what output is produced? What should the output look like instead?

Comment: The output looks like this:
`{'Mac': {'Exam 3': '111'}, 'Thorny': {'Exam 3': '80'}, 'Farva': {'Exam 3': '67'}, 'Ursula': {'Exam 3': '83'}, 'Rabbit': {'Exam 3': '67'}, 'Foster': {'Exam 3': '101'}}`

Comment: `{name: {col: int(value) for col, value in zip(grades_list[0][1:], row)} for name, *row in grades_list[1:]}` is probably what you wanted.

Comment: @AshBellett: please [edit] your question to add the requested information.

Comment: @user202729: because we are guessing at what the expected output might be. And the point is that **future visitors with the same question** can figure out if they have the same problem.

Comment: This data structure looks a lot like the one in a question posted yesterday: [Nested dictionary - iteration off](//stackoverflow.com/q/48209017)

Comment: I would like the dictionary to look like this:
`{'Bella': {'Test': 80, 'Assignment': 90, 'Exam': 100}, 'Sam': {'Test': 65, 'Assignment': 75, 'Exam': 85}, 'Emily': {'Test': 60, 'Assignment': 75, 'Exam': 90}}`

Comment: @AshBellett: again, that info belongs in your question, please [edit] it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got your nesting mixed up. The following works:

```
{name: {col: int(value) for col, value in zip(grades_list[0][1:], row)}
 for name, *row in grades_list[1:]}
```

The `for name, *row in ...` loop takes each row, and extracts just the first value into `name`, the remainder into `row` (the `*` tells Python to take the remainder). This lets you then use the row together with the column names from the first row to create the nested dictionaries.

It is often easier to see what a comprehension does by using regular loops. Your code does this:

```
grade_dicts = {}
for y in grades_lists[0][1:]:
    for x in grades_lists[1:]:
        for z in x[1:]:
            grade_dicts[x[0]] = {y:z}
```

That's way too many loops, and you end up setting a value for `x[0]` several times; `len(x[1:])` times in fact. Only the last `{y: z}` dictionary remains.

My version does this:

```
grade_dicts = {}
for name, *row in grades_list[1:]:
    inner = {}
    for col, value in zip(grades_list[0][1:], row):
        inner[col] = int(value)
    grade_dicts[name] = inner
```

That's just two loops, where the inner produces a separate dictionary for each column. I used `zip()` to pair up the labels and the values.